# Android camera recording time limit and maximum size

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-mediarecorder, max-size

How to set Android camera recording time duration limit and maximum size.I have tried a lot with intents and mediaRecorder Both.But No one works properly for me.
Is any proper solution for these issue?

Log

```
07-01 03:59:06.493 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e15ffe8 time:15810029
07-01 03:59:09.346 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.enventpc_03.nav11 time:15812882
07-01 03:59:09.490 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.enventpc_03.nav11 time:15813026
07-01 03:59:09.917 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-01 03:59:10.126 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.enventpc_03.nav11 time:15813662
07-01 03:59:10.352 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.enventpc_03.nav11 time:15813888
07-01 03:59:10.387 16782-16809/com.enventpc_03.nav11 V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
07-01 03:59:10.395 16782-16809/com.enventpc_03.nav11 V/RenderScript: 0x5592449c50 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
07-01 03:59:11.068 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 V/PhoneWindow: updateColorViewInt()if drawable=null color=-16777216
07-01 03:59:11.199 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@213dad01 time:15814735
07-01 03:59:11.199 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1fb240d9 time:15814735
07-01 04:00:50.363 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@213dad01 time:15913899
07-01 04:00:55.746 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.enventpc_03.nav11 time:15919282
07-01 04:00:55.920 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 V/PhoneWindow: updateColorViewInt()if drawable=null color=-16777216
07-01 04:00:56.173 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@158377d9 time:15919709
07-01 04:01:42.727 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.enventpc_03.nav11 time:15966263
07-01 04:01:42.925 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/UploadApp: file path is null
07-01 04:01:43.323 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/VideoView: Open Video
07-01 04:01:43.335 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
07-01 04:01:43.337 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/VideoView: SetDataSource
07-01 04:01:43.339 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-01 04:01:43.552 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
07-01 04:01:43.839 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 V/PhoneWindow: updateColorViewInt()if drawable=null color=-16777216
07-01 04:01:43.879 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@239081f2 time:15967415
07-01 04:01:43.879 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@158377d9 time:15967415
07-01 04:02:19.015 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/VideoView: Playback Start begin
07-01 04:02:19.016 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 I/VideoView: Playback Start end
07-01 04:02:19.035 16782-16782/com.enventpc_03.nav11 V/PhoneWindow: updateColorViewInt()else drawable=null color=-16777216
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the values in your `intent` using the `MediaStore` properties.

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        .putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 15) //15s Limit
        .putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, (5*1048*1048)+"L"), 0); //5MB Limit
```

Comment: this code is not working most of mobile phones such as lenovo, mi honor..

Comment: Could you post a log and which version you're testing on?